# How to add custom row in totals section after grand total row?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, totals

I need to add a custom row below grand total row. I have tried code from

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/

It adds custom row but above grand total. I have tried to add a large value to tag **totals_sort** in **config.xml** but it is not working.

Also when I pass value for custom row it is formatted to amount with store currency. Like if I pass value as 100 then in totals section it will be shown as **$100**. But I need to show it as **100 ABC**

**EDIT**

Please see screen shot below.

[image]

Comment: did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious but totals have 2 different areas: main (code `null`) and footer (code `footer`). Regardless how do you sort your custom total it will always be above grand total (which is in a footer area) if it is in a main area.

So the solution is quite straightforward - add your total to footer area too. In order to do so in an array that `fetch` method of your total class returns add `'area' => 'footer'`.